# Locii of vertices of parallelograms

Tags: geometry, locus

$ABCD$ is a given parallelogram. What is the locus of the remaining vertices of a parallelogram equal in area to $ABCD$ having $AC$ as its diagonal?

I came up with the answer that the remaining vertices will have a locus as lines parallel to the diagonal $AC$.

Am I correct?

Comment: Seems like it. $AC$ splits the parallelogram into two triangles. In order for the area to stay the same, the height of these triangles must stay the same, so B and D must stay the same distance from $AC$. They can only then move "left" and "right" relative to $AC$, thus creating two parallel lines. You should probably specify that the two lines are equidistant from $AC$

Comment: Thank buddy for just adding specs to my answer

Answer (score 1):

Yep.  To illustrate, draw with AC horizontal, origin in the middle.  If B and D are located at $(x,y)$ and $(-x,-y)$, the shape will be a parallelogram, and the area will be $|AC|\cdot |y|$.

Thus the loci you are seeking are horizontal lines, which are parallel to AC.